# Need help understanding async/promises with mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "host",
    user: "login",
    password: "password",
    database: "db"
});

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");

    function addTalentPoint(id,amount){
        var sql = "SELECT RegValue FROM `Registry` WHERE RegChaId="+id+" AND RegIdentifier='TalentPoints'"

        var endingTalentPoint = 0;

        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Starting Talent Point: "+result[0].RegValue);
            endingTalentPoint = result[0].RegValue + amount

            var sql = "UPDATE `Registry` SET RegValue="+endingTalentPoint+" WHERE RegChaId="+id+" AND RegIdentifier='TalentPoints'"
            con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
                console.log(endingTalentPoint)
            });
        });


    }
    function getTalentPoint(id){
        var sql = "SELECT RegValue FROM `Registry` WHERE RegChaId="+id+" AND RegIdentifier='TalentPoints'"

        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("get talent point: "+result[0].RegValue);
        });
    }

    addTalentPoint(4,5)
    getTalentPoint(4)
});
```

My example output:

> Starting Talent Point: 125
>
> get talent point: 125
>
> 130

I have read through numerous blogs and tried using async / await and setting up promises but I'm not getting where I need to be. I'm trying to get the code to wait for addTalentPoint to finish before getTalentPoint executes. Is it just the nature of the beast that it sends the query off, and then continues on with the code? I could put getTalentPoint inside the callback under the UPDATE, but how can I know the update finished?

Comment: Then you need to call `getTalentPoint` inside the `addTalentPoint` callbacks. Else it's just going to execute immediately. Or use a callback/promise from `getTalentPoint`

Answer (score -1):

`addTalentPoint` is still doing async stuff - all those `con.query` calls are async - so unless you do the work in the callbacks, things will just be executed immediately (like your `getTalentPoint` function) - one solution would be to add a callback function to the `addTalentPoint` function. See the below changes:

```
//First, add a callback parameter
function addTalentPoint(id,amount,callback){
    ...
    //next, use this callback when the work is done
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(endingTalentPoint)
    if (callback) callback(); //if a callback exists, call it
```

Now, use your new param:

```
addTalentPoint(4,5, function() {
    //All done doing the work in addTalentPoint, lets do more things now!
    getTalentPoint(4)
})
```